# Wordpress customizing a walker menu class

Tags: menus, walker

Hey Folks I trying to customize a wordpress walker class to add custom classes to navigation level. Essentially there will be 3 levels of navigation.

Here's the code:

`<ul class="rd-navbar-nav">
  <li class="rd-nav-item active"><a class="rd-nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="rd-nav-item rd-navbar--has-dropdown rd-navbar-submenu"><a class="rd-nav-link" href="#">Activities</a></span>
  <ul class="rd-menu rd-navbar-dropdown">
    <li class="rd-dropdown-item"><a class="rd-dropdown-link" href="#">Classic Blog</a></li>
    <li class="rd-dropdown-item"><a class="rd-dropdown-link" href="#">Blog Post</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>`

Comment: Did you manage the modification of the menu?

Answer (score 0):

If you want change only CSS classes, you can use filters 
`nav_menu_submenu_css_class` (for **`<ul>`** element, [codex](http://[2]:https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_submenu_css_class/)) and `nav_menu_css_class` (for **`<li>`**, [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_css_class/)).

Example of usage:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_menu_item_class' , 20 , 4);

function special_menu_item_class($classes, $item, $args, $depth) {
    // add or replace classes
    $classes[] = 'rd-nav-item';
    if ($args->has_children) {
        $classes[] = 'rd-navbar--has-dropdown';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```